# PHP - How to remove duplicate array elements when print from inner loop based on the number of elemenets

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

```
$sports = array
(
    array('id'=> 1, 'Name'=>'Soccer','Popularity'=>'High'),
    array('id' => 2,'Name'=>'Baseball','Popularity'=>'Low', 'IsTrending' => 'Yes')

);

$sport_history = array(
    array('OwnerId' => 1, 'View'=>'Worldwide'),
    array('OwnerId'=> 1, 'View'=>'Usa'),
    array('OwnerId'=> 1, 'View'=>'Europe'),
);

foreach($sports as $masterKey => $sport){

    if($sport['IsTrending'] == 'Yes'){

         var_dump($sport['Name']);//Here only prints onces

        foreach ($sport_history as $key=>$history){

            var_dump($sport['Name']);//Here prints several times but I would like to be printed here and based on the number of elements in the first array and not the second.

            echo '<pre>' . print_r($sport_history[$key],1) . '</pre>';

        }
    }
}
```

I'm having an issue where the first array value is output multiple times when placing inside of second inner loop but when placed on the outter loop it prints only once. I want to be able to output the values in the inner loop based on the number of elements on array and not the outter loop. I was thinking in using "if not inarray()" or "array_uniquie()" but not sure.

**UPDATE:**
Desire output:
Instead of this

```
string(8) "Baseball"
Array
(
    [OwnerId] => 1
    [View] => Worldwide
)
string(8) "Baseball"
Array
(
    [OwnerId] => 1
    [View] => Usa
)
string(8) "Baseball"
Array
(
    [OwnerId] => 1
    [View] => Europe
)
```

**I want this within the inner loop**

```
string(8) "Baseball"
Array
(
    [OwnerId] => 1
    [View] => Worldwide
)
Array
(
    [OwnerId] => 1
    [View] => Usa
)
Array
(
    [OwnerId] => 1
    [View] => Europe
)
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Why not just output the sport name in the outer loop instead of the inner one?

Comment: Please, be more clear. Write the desired output.

Comment: @Nick because I want to do an insert into a database table that requires a sport id .

Comment: Perhaps you could show that code?

Comment: @Nick I updated my code.

Comment: @Stefano Coletta - I updated the code as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output you want (since you want to perform the output in the inner loop) by just outputting for the first key in `$sport_history`. Based on your code, that will be 0 so change

```
var_dump($sport['Name']);
```

to

```
if ($key == 0) var_dump($sport['Name']);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but what about if there are multiple elements? $key == 0 refers to the first index matching 0 correct?

Comment: Correct - but there will only be one index in `$sport_history` matching 0, which should be the first one.

Comment: Ok sir thanks, I'll try now and if it works, I'll let you know shortly.

Comment: Just tried it out and it works! Thank you Nick. Just what I needed.